# What a better used for post file. IOS

Tags: ios, multipartform-data

I need to send image File on PHP server $_FILE. multipart/form-data.
What need to used?
NSURLSession, NSURLConnection, or something else?
And please write example.

When used

```
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@; filename=imageName.jpg\r\n", @"imageFormKey"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

post is 
     --

```
 --
     Content-Disposition: form-data; name   "avatar[image]"; filename="image.jpg"
     Content-Type: application/octet-stream

     ¤Ў¤аJFIF¤бXExifMM*Зi††ф†ф¤џC¤џC¤јфф¤ƒ¤ƒµ}!1AQa"q2БС°#B±ЅR—р$3brВ%         '()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzГДЕЖЗИЙКТУФХЦЧШЩЪ¢        £§•¶І®©™≤≥іµ∂ЈЄєЇ¬√ƒ≈∆«»… “”‘’÷„ЎўЏбвгдежзийкстуфхцчшщъ¤ƒ   
¤ƒµw!1AQaq"2БBС°±Ѕ  #3Rрbr—
    $4б%с   
'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzВГДЕЖЗИЙКТУФХЦЧШЩЪ¢£§•¶І®©™≤≥іµ∂ЈЄєЇ¬√ƒ≈∆«»… “”‘’÷„ЎўЏвгдежзийктуфхцчшщъ¤Џ?юю(†А
(†А
(†А
(†А
(†А
(†А
(аш{ьЋюТYывd~ќњьсищ°ш„¤Є~≈ъЕl/?gOЎгцЯш©гy<Akm™x{г^їрІаЕlь*ъvЂ-ц≥aгшЫцФ’х/[криvVЊЄр.ХІ^iЏОЂ™MвЋЭ”G„@>@сgь'вЂѕ
шЪ”јњрMOшs∆ч^÷mЉв~÷zПН< °x™}:ж/k>   
рvПы:xWсgЗфљ]≠/µЯ
i~:р^£Ѓй–\йv^,реЌ‘Z≈ШƒсЈь7юИм¤Ж≥цК¤и™†£~Ѕ“_рp7нбЂпь¤Вnь
шяаэ3\єр∆•вѕД±пн≠с+√ZЙlђ4ЌVу√„ЏпГ?h kKі„-4љkF‘ЃtЫЛ®па∞’іЋ…m÷ёю÷I/гoьр„5√д^#xљбgxЉЊЦmЕ…ЄџПшSЕs\NU_ЛЅ–ћрщ~{Ы`1u≤ъЎЉ;KNМ∞’18<]TХ\=h√Ј
Цж8»:ЄL7N3tеS
Еѓ^
```

and so on...

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete example. Hint: use AFNetworking is an easier choice; and seek tutorial in Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial) should help you. NSURLSession was added to iOS 7 to replace NSURLConnection, so that is probably your best bet. The tutorial shows you how to post images.

Hope it helps!